# Issues on Calculator Program of repeated num1 and num2 for else in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement

I decided to program a Calculator, but my Problem is if i made a **choice** and entered 6 it still ask's me for **num1** and **num2** before saying "Invalid Input, PLease check the *Select Operation* and Try Again!". What i want is for it to go directly to saying "Invalid Input, PLease check the *Select Operation* and Try Again!" without requesting **num1** and **num2**. I hope it's clear.

```
def calculator():
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def sub(x, y):
    return x - y

def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

def div(x, y):
    return x / y

print(""" -- Select Operation --
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
""")

choice = input("Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 from the Select Operation >> ")
print("\n")
print("Calculating...")
num1 = int(input("Enter First number >> "))
num2 = int(input("Enter Second number >> "))

if choice == '1':
    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
elif choice == '2':
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
elif choice == '3':
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
elif choice == '4':
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
else:
    print("Invalid Input, PLease check the *Select Operation* and Try Again!")
```

calculator()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your code please read python syntax

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def sub(x, y):
    return x - y

def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

def div(x, y):
    return x / y

print(""" -- Select Operation --
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
""")

choice = input("Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 from the Select Operation >> ")
while(choice not in ('1','2','3','4')):
  choice = input("Invalid Input Please Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 from the Select Operation >> ")
print("\n")
print("Calculating...")
num1 = int(input("Enter First number >> "))
num2 = int(input("Enter Second number >> "))

if choice == '1':
    print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
elif choice == '2':
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", sub(num1, num2))
elif choice == '3':
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", mul(num1, num2))
elif choice == '4':
    print(num1, "-", num2, "=", div(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I guess am still trying to understand while loop, i need more examples on it.

Comment: Please Accept the answer @EmpressObazee